# Generate a source file that may or may not be updated

Tags: c++, cmake, code-generation

I have a CMakeLists.txt in which I want to generate several source files (namely, `versiondata.cpp` and `version.rc.inc`, included by `res.rc`) that depends on the general environment (current git HEAD, `gcc -v` output, `CMakeCache.txt` itself, and so on).

If it depended just on some files, I would generate it using an `add_custom_command` directive with the relevant `DEPENDS` and `OUTPUT` clauses; however, it's a bit tricky to pinpoint exactly its *file* dependencies; ideally, I'd want to run my script every time I call `make`, updating the files only if needed; if the generated files have actually been touched, then the targets depending from them should be rebuilt (the script is careful not to overwrite the files if they would have the same content as before).

My first attempt was using an `add_custom_command` with a fake main output, like this:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT versiondata.cpp.fake versiondata.cpp version.rc.inc
    COMMAND my_command my_options
    COMMENT "Generating versiondata.cpp"
)
# ...
# explicitly set the dependencies of res.rc, as they are not auto-deduced
set_source_files_properties(res.rc PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/version.rc.inc;${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/other_stuff.ico")
# ...
add_executable(my_executable WIN32 ALL main.cpp versiondata.cpp res.rc)
```

`versiondata.cpp.fake` is never really generated, so the custom command is always run. This worked correctly, but always rebuilt `my_executable`, as CMake for some reasons automatically touches the output files (if generated) even though my script left them alone.

Then I thought I might make it work using an `add_custom_target`, that is automatically "never already satisfied":

```
add_custom_target(versiondata BYPRODUCTS versiondata.cpp version.rc.inc
    COMMAND my_command my_options
    COMMENT "Generating versiondata.cpp"
)
# ...
# explicitly set the dependencies of res.rc, as they are not auto-deduced
set_source_files_properties(res.rc PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/version.rc.inc;${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/other_stuff.ico")
# ...
add_executable(my_executable WIN32 ALL main.cpp versiondata.cpp res.rc)
```

The idea here is that the `versiondata` target should be "pulled in" from the targets that depend on its `BYPRODUCTS`, and should be always executed. This seems to work on CMake 3.20, and the `BYPRODUCTS` seem to have some effect because if I remove the dependencies from `my_executable` my script doesn't get called.

However, on CMake 3.5 I get

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'version.rc.inc', needed by 'CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/res.rc.res'.  Stop.
```

and if I remove the explicit dependency from `version.rc.inc` it doesn't get generated at all

```
[ 45%] Building RC object CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/res.rc.res
/co/my_executable/res.rc:386:26: fatal error: version.rc.inc: No such file or directory
 #include "version.rc.inc"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
/opt/mingw32-dw2/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-windres: preprocessing failed.
CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/build.make:5080: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/res.rc.res' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_executable.dir/res.rc.res] Error 1
```

so I suspect that the fact that this works in 3.20 is just by chance.

Long story short: is there some way to make this work as I wish?

Comment: "I suspect that the fact that this works in 3.20 is just by chance" - No, this behavior is perfectly [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html): since CMake 3.16 DEPEND-ing from the BYPRODUCTS generates **target-level** dependency. In your case this is dependency between the executable target `my_executable` and the custom target `versiondata`. You could specify this dependency explicitly by `add_dependencies(my_executable versiondata)`, so the building will work even in CMake pre-3.16.

Comment: There is absolutely no merit to being compatible with version 3.5

Comment: @Tsyvarev if true, that's good to know, although I wouldn't say it's "perfectly documented": the section I think you are quoting is under the `DEPENDS` section for `add_custom_target`, which, as it's written, would apply to custom targets which depend from byproducts, not for other kinds of target. If that applies to targets in general, it should be under `BYPRODUCTS` IMO. So, an explicit `add_dependencies` is the only way in pre-3.16 CMake? I'm baffled, although with CMake I really shouldn't be.

Comment: @AlexReinking: and, while we are at it, there is also absolutely no merit to using CMake instead of some better alternative, yet here we are. Sometimes there are complex constraints and you have to choose the lesser evil, and if I'm going out of my way testing a specific older CMake version it may be one of those cases.

Comment: Any constraint that says you have to use an outdated CMake version is bogus and more than a bit masochistic. The further back you go, the more you run into ridiculous problems like this one where basic things don't work the way they should and you waste time solving "problems" that you should never encounter in the first place.

Comment: Again, I'm well aware that CMake sucks and the older you go, the more it sucks, thank you very much; I've transitioned a lot of our build infrastructure to modern, target-based CMake with transitive dependencies/propagated options and stuff, so I think I have my experience with it. If I say that I tested it CMake 3.5 it's not because I have nothing better to do or don't know how to install an upgraded version, but because there's an actual problem. As a general rule, don't assume the person you are talking to is stupid because their constraints don't align with what you'd like them to be.

Comment: @fabian: what advantage does it give having an extra library compared to just having it as a file in the final target? Even in that case I just need to compile the single file and relink the executable (which is what I'm trying to avoid, though, unfortunately linking this project takes 10 seconds). `execute_process` is not ok, as it's executed at configure time, while I need it to happen at build time.

Comment: What is wrong in using explicit `add_dependencies`, so it will work both in newer and older CMake? Initially, CMake used BYPRODUCTS only for support Ninja. Later, CMake developers found out that BYPRODUCTS could be treated as some sort of additional dependencies, which could be interpreted similarly to DEPENDS by adding target-level dependencies. You want your project to be compatible with CMake 3.5. Nice. So just write `CMakeLists.txt` for given CMake version, without using new features.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: that's what I'm doing now (thank you for your comment BTW), I was just wondering if there was some better way without having to spoonfeed CMake. Also, if you want to post it as an answer I can accept it in a few days if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMake there are two types of dependencies:

1. Target-level dependency, between **targets**.

   A target can be build only after **unconditional** building of all targets it depends on.
2. File-level dependency, between **files**.

   If some file is older than one of its dependencies, the file will be regenerated using corresponded `COMMAND`.

The key factor is that checking for timestamp of dependent **files** is performed strictly **after** building of dependent **targets**.

For correct regeneration of `versiondata.cpp` file and executable based on it, one need both dependencies:

1. Target-level, which would ensure that `versiondata` custom target
   will be built before the executable.

   ```
   add_dependencies(my_executable versiondata)
   ```
2. File-level, which will ensure that the executable will be rebuilt whenever
   file `versiondata.cpp` will be updated.

   This dependency is created automatically by listing `versiondata.cpp`
   among the sources for the executable.

---

Now about BYPRODUCTS.

Even without explicit `add_dependencies`, your code works on CMake 3.20 because BYPRODUCTS generates needed target-level dependency **automatically**.

This could be deduced from the description of `DEPENDS` option in [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html)/[add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html):

> *Changed in version 3.16*: A target-level dependency is added if any dependency is a byproduct of a target or any of its build events in the same directory to ensure the byproducts will be available before this target is built.

and noting, that `add_executable` effectively depends on every of its source files.

Because given comment for DEPENDS is applicable only for CMake 3.16 and later,
in older CMake versions BYPRODUCTS does not create target-level dependency *automatically*, and one need to resort to explicit `add_dependencies`.